# Custom UINavigationController Animation Unresponsive When Finished

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to make a slide animation for my navigation controller transitions. For instance, when I push a VC, the presenting and the presented VCs will transition just like a `UIPageViewController` transition.

Here is what I've coded so far:

```
guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from),
      let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)
  else { return }

  let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

  toView.frame = CGRect(x: -toViewFrameHorizationtalPosition,
                        y: 64,
                        width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                        height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

  containerView.addSubview(fromView)
  containerView.addSubview(toView)

  UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
                 delay: 0,
                 options: .curveEaseInOut,
                 animations: {
                   containerView.frame.origin.x = self.toViewFrameHorizationtalPosition
  }) { completed in
    transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
  }
```

The transition animation is happening as I expected it to be but even though against various tries, once the animation executes the view becomes unresponsive; it does not recognise any touch events.

The navigation bar works fine but when I switch back to the initial view, that view is unresponsive as well.

I've read a lot on this and been struggling with this for a while now although I can't seem to spot the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: First, your `fromView` should already be in the `containerView` so no need to addSubview again. Next, it looks like you are changing the frame of `containerView` ... but don't you really want to change the frame of either `fromView` or `toView` (or both) *inside* `containerView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright then, I finally found the solution. Many many thanks to @DonMag for pointing me in the right direction with his great comment!

First off, as @DonMag has also mentioned, it was needless of me to add the `fromView` into the `containerView` as it's already present inside there.

Anyways, the problem with the presented view, `toView`, being unresponsive was that for the purposes of making the slide animation:

- I was changing the x value of the `toView`s frame origin to position it right inside the container view,
- and moving the container view again by changing it's x value of it's frame origin. I'm moving the container view because I want both the `fromView` and the `toView` to act one next to the other, i.e. just like how a UIPageViewController animates.

The problem was that I was not setting them back to their original values. Once I set `toView`s and `containerView`s frame origins back to their original values in the animation completion block, everything worked as expected.

Here is the revised animation code:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)
        else { return }

    toView.removeFromSuperview()
    toView.frame = CGRect(x: -toViewFrameHorizationtalPosition,
                          y: 64,
                          width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                          height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
    containerView.addSubview(toView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
                   delay: 0,
                   options: .curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                                    containerView.frame.origin.x = self.toViewFrameHorizationtalPosition
    }) { completed in
        containerView.frame.origin.x = 0
        toView.frame.origin.x = 0
        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    }
}
```

P.S. Again, many many thanks to @DonMag. Your insight has been really helpful.